# How to set the value of one field to another filed in using XQuery

Tags: xquery, marklogic

Very new to XQuery and MarkLogic, what is the XQuery version of the following statement?

```
update all_the_records 
set B_field = A_field 
where B_field is null and A_field is not null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this might get you started. But remember that you're working with trees, not tables. Things are generally more complicated because of that extra dimension.

```
for $doc in collection()/doc[not(b)][a]
let $a as element() := $doc/a
return xdmp:node-insert-child($doc, element b { $a/@*, $a/node() })
```

Comment: i ended up doing it like this actually, my assumption was that the both nodes exist 
      node-replace($btag ,<btag>$a/text()</btag>)